# 'Cannot create temporary ouput file' while running tests

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

Here is my configuration:

[image]

When I am trying to run the tests I get the error `Cannot create temporary ouput file`. As I see the is no setting for `Output directory` here.

How can I run the tests in Gogland ?

Comment: It's a bug. It will be fixed next version. As a workaround remove `:` from Run configuration name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your working directory is correct?

`D:` looks like Windows

`/development/gopath/`... is Linux

Comment: Yes, I am working on Windows.  And the same working directory works fine to run the program, not tests.

Answer (score 2):

There are likely multiple issues that can cause this, and thus multiple solutions that could solve the corresponding issue. But here is one more thing to try.

1. Go to your test Run/Debug Configurations (ie: the "Edit Configurations" line in the tests dropdown).
2. At the bottom/left of the list of tests, there should be some clickable text that says "Edit Configuration Templates...". Click that & it will open a window called "Run/Debug Configuration Templates" that allows editing of your general test template configurations for various testing libraries.
3. In the GoTest library's configuration template, check the "Run with sudo", which should enable GoLand to have permissions to create the output file it needs during testing.
4. Restart (quit & re-open) the GoLand program.
5. Attempt to run your test from scratch. *(Per the notice in the Run/Debug Configuration Templates, changes will only affect **new** test runs & their configurations, it does not affect existing test runs & their configurations, so don't just try to re-run an old configuration)*.

[image: Run GoLand tests with sudo]

That fixed my testing woes, hope it fixes yours.